# Laravel: Multiple if conditions in single line in Laravel blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.4

In a web app, I have a link which sorts the data in ASC/DESC order. I want my link to in a default condition first and when clicked first time it will sort data in ASC order, and if clicked again it will make it DESC order.

`http//localhost/master/branch/` - Default url

`http//localhost/master/branch/?sort=name&dir=asc` - First time user clicked link

`http//localhost/master/branch/?sort=name&dir=desc` - Again the same link is clicked

I need to modify the icons of the link based on the deafult/asc/desc orders. I have put following condition in anchor tag, but that doesn't look to be working:

`<a href="{{ route('branch.index') }}?sort=name&dir={{ Request::input('dir') == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc' }}">Name</a> <i class="fa fa-{{ !Request::input('dir') ? 'sort' : '(Request::input('dir') == 'asc' ? sort-alpha-asc' : 'sort-alpha-desc'.' }}"></i>`

But the above gives `FatalErrorException` and says `syntax error, unexpected 'dir' (T_STRING)`

Please advise how I can add multiple condition in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are redundant `'` and `.` in your code, or you can escape them. You can try this,

```
<a href="{{ route('branch.index') }}?sort=name&dir={{ Request::input('dir') == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc' }}">Name</a>
<i class="fa fa-{{ !Request::input('dir') ? 'sort' : (Request::input('dir') == 'asc' ? 'sort-alpha-asc' : 'sort-alpha-desc') }}"></i>
```

Comment: Looks great and working. perfect. But in your code, we need `'` before `sort-alpha-asc` all else is good. I have edited your answer, please check.  Thanks for helping.